# Child themes: disabling the parent

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, parent-theme

I'm creating a parent theme and several child themes. But how can I prevent the parent theme from ever being used?

Comment: It might help get a better answer if you explain your use case of not wanting the parent theme from ever being used.

Comment: I'm guessing that he doesn't want anyone to be able to select the parent theme from the Themes admin selection page.

Comment: The parent theme provides common functionality for all the child themes - say 90% of the templates. But it wouldn't make sense to use it on its own.

Comment: sounds like "abstract themes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using the current system. In order to serve as a valid Template for a Child Theme, the Parent Theme must exist, and be a valid Theme. That's because the Parent Theme's template files must be accessible via `locate_template()`, in order for the Child-Parent fallback to work properly.

Note: if [this core Trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13239) is implemented, then you'll be able to filter `locate_template()`, which would conceivably enable you to put your Parent Theme in a separate location, not accessible by `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Themes`.

Answer (score 1):

would - by ensuring the child theme had all the same template pages as the parent and by not including the @import of the parent css - be too dumb of an answer?

Comment: that's an interesting approach, but then you start to lose the benefits of having a parent theme at all - at some point you might as well just clone the theme and make changes directly!

Comment: You have to get creative & interesting in order to achieve something you have no knowledge of how to do lol

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide the theme itself, but you can control access to the theme switcher:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#switch_themes